# Let CtrlP show all files including the file being edited

Tags: plugin-ctrlp

If I open CtrlP in the standard "files" mode I can't find the currently opened file.

I would like to change this behavior: I would like to see all files including the current opened file.

I there a way to change this?

(I couldn't find any such open in the help file)

Comment: How do you open ctrlp in "the standard file mode"? When I do `:CtrlP` it lists all the files in the directory no matter if they are open in a buffer or not and when I do `:CtrlPBuffer` it lists only the files open in a buffer.

Comment: I just press Ctrl-P. OK, it only filters out the current (active) buffer.

Comment: Oh then that's just an option to change :) Let me find that again

Comment: Updated question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`:h 'g:ctrlp_match_current_file'`](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim/blob/master/doc/ctrlp.txt#L459):

> Includes the current file in the match entries:
>
> `let g:ctrlp_match_current_file = 1`

You can add the line to your vimrc if you want the behavior to be permanent.

Comment: Can't find this option... I'm using v1.79. The latest version from https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim

Comment: @BorisBrodski It is [here](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim/blob/master/doc/ctrlp.txt#L459) in the doc of the master branch

Comment: Thank you! I upgraded URL to https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim and everything works now!